# Updating attributes on the image caused the node to be deselected in tiptap

Tags: vue.js, tiptap

I'm developing an image extension but I've run into an issue that causes nodes to be deselected when I update the image properties

```
import Image from '@tiptap/extension-image';
...
extensions: [
      ...
      Image.configure({
        inline: true,
      }),
    ]
```

I inserted a picture

```
editor.chain().focus().setImage({
   src: 'https://xxxx'
 }).run();
```

and then, after selecting the image,

```
editor.chain().focus().updateAttributes('image', {
   title: 'Hello'
 }).run();
```

the bubble menu for my images disappear after each attribute updates，the css class 'ProseMirror-selectednode' is being removed from the node

The node is deselected but shouldn't

---

my current plan is as follows. I don’t know if it’s right, but it works for me.

```
editor.chain().focus().updateAttributes('image', {
   title: 'Hello'
 }).setNodeSelection(editor.view.state.selection.anchor).run();
```